# Mongodb throwing syntax error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to enter some values in a mongo database using node.js but I am getting an error.

The first line of my .js file is:

```
var Db= require("mongodb").Db,
```

I am getting an error:

```
/home/vijay/noder/dbase/mongo.js:1

(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { jar Db= require(
                                                              ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

There is another problem, I get `mongod stop/waiting`, when I enter 
`sudo service mongod status` on my terminal (this happens after I've already done `sudo service mongod start` in the terminal)

Comment: Shouldn't `jar` just be `var`?

Comment: 'jar' is what the terminal says!

Comment: Yes but `jar` is a syntax error.  It is not legal JavaScript.  That's why an error was reported.  You need to fix that mongo.js file.

Comment: I understood that, as I have stated above (in the question), first line of code in the mongo.js file is: `var Db= require("mongodb").Db` and not `jar Db= require("mongodb").Db`

Answer (score 0):

Reason for error - I used double quotes " in place of single quotes ' o_O

**So the correct form was: var Db= require('mongodb').Db** 
// and not var Db= require("mongodb").Db,

Comment: That doesn't make any sense as those two forms are equivalent.

Comment: I thought the same before I made the change!

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```